# How to get Django Form to return the same page

Tags: django, forms

I have a form that I've been working on, currently displaying in a template called search_test.html, that I've finally gotten working right. I want to actually integrate it into my site, but on my site it's not going to be its own page, it's going to be a sidebar that's present on most pages. I know when I do that, this line

```
return render_to_response('corpus/search_test.html', 
                                  {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

is going to give me problems, because I don't want to actually redirect to search_test.html.

What can I replace this 'render_to_response' with, to tell it to just stay on the same page, but still pass the form info? I know this has got to be something simple, but I've looked all over online and in the docs and I can't find a similar example. (The view code for the form is below.)

Thank you.

```
def concord_test(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ConcordanceForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            searchterm = form.cleaned_data['searchterm'].encode('utf-8')
            search_type = form.cleaned_data['search_type']
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            context, texts_len, results_len = make_concordance(searchterm, search_type, cat=category)
            return render_to_response('corpus/concord.html', locals()) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ConcordanceForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('corpus/search_test.html', 
                              {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Did you try ajax request??

Answer (score 0):

In a function page view (as per example)
you can do something like

```
def other_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        return concord_test(request)
    else:
        form = ConcordanceForm() 

        #Processing for other_page
        object_list = OtherPageModel.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('corpus/other_page.html', 
                          {'form': form , 'object_list': object_list }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my advice: study class based views , you can have more granular capabilities dealing with  'repetitive' tasks like this & more.

Comment: I don't understand: isn't this just tying the form to other_page, rather than having it be independent of whatever page is on. And I don't understand what object_list is doing here ... Unless, I'm completely misunderstanding you, this doesn't seem to be addressing my question at all. Also, which "repetitive tasks" are you referring to?